# How to generate alert if duration of data coming from server is more than 6 hrs using prometheus

Tags: java, spring-boot, alert, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I want to generate alert if duration of data coming from server is more than x number of hours.

My code is to get the data:

```
 metrics.incrementCounter("TOTAL_NUM_SUCCESS_OF_REQUEST" , vendorName);
```

Comment: Please read [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236)

Comment: What do you mean by `more than x number of hours`? Greater than a threshold in a certain timespan?